# Exclude some arguments from the minimization

Tags: python, scipy-optimize-minimize

If I have a function `func(x1,x2,x3)`, can I use the minimize function  `scipy.optimize.minimize` with excluding `x3` from the optimization process, where `x3` is defined as `numpy array`.
How can I define the argument in this case?. I'm supposed to get an array containing the minimum values of `func` for each value of `x3`.

For example:

```
def func(thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2,c2):
    
    RhoABC = np.array([[1,0,thet1,0,0,0,0,c1],[0,1,0,0,phai2,0,c2,0],[0,0,1,0,0,c2,thet2,0],[0,0,0,1,c2,0,0,0],[0,phai1,0,c2,1,0,0,0],[0,0,c2,0,0,1,0,thet2],[0,c2,0,0,0,0,1,0],[c1,0,0,phai1,0,0,0,1]])   
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(RhoABC)  
    return w[1]
```

I want to minimize it where `c2 = linspace(-1,1,10)` and the angles belong to `(0,2pi)`

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but you could use *args and then put the argument x3, this way, you don't have to assign it a value every time you call it.

Comment: @jimmie_roggers Thank you for your reply. I think this is a solution to my problem but I don't know how to implement it. I made my question clear, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
def func(thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2,*args, c2 = []):
#considering c2 to be x3 in the above post
    
    RhoABC = np.array([[1,0,thet1,0,0,0,0,c1],[0,1,0,0,phai2,0,c2,0],[0,0,1,0,0,c2,thet2,0],[0,0,0,1,c2,0,0,0],[0,phai1,0,c2,1,0,0,0],[0,0,c2,0,0,1,0,thet2],[0,c2,0,0,0,0,1,0],[c1,0,0,phai1,0,0,0,1]])   
    w, v = np.linalg.eig(RhoABC)  
    return w[1]
```

Then when you call the function:

```
retVal = func(thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2, c2=c2)

#you have to specify c2 first and then equate it to the value since this is an optional argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to jimmie's answer, you can use a lambda function and the unpacking operator `*`:

```
minimize(lambda x: func(*x, linspace(-1,1,10)), x0=x0, ...)
```

will minimize the function `func` for the variables `thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2` with given `c2=linspace(-1,1,10)`.

Comment: In this case, would 
`def func(thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2,*args, c2 = []):`
remain as it is?

Comment: @Bekaso No, it's your initial function signature, i.e. `def func(thet1,phai1,thet2,phai2,c2)`.